# PHP complex SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MySQL, I want to echo a list of products from my products table in my database. I also want to echo only 3 most recent reviews for each product below the product. Is there a way I can do this without putting a sql query inside a loop. I want no more than 2 sql queries in the script

Comment: This is usually done with a loop - it's likely to include more than one table. It's probably not going to be worth building an insanely complex query (that is going to take longer and eat up more resources) just in order to have less queries in the script

Comment: we could help you,if you give us more info...like the code you have written so far?or your database schema?

Comment: You can do it with using MySQL query variables, but I would need a little more structure to your tables to see the relationships and what basis of content you want.

Comment: Can you tell us what tables you have and how you track reviews? Once you've added this information you can flag to re-open. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, since there is not much info to go on.

```
SELECT 
   product.stuff, 
   review.stuff
FROM         
   product 
INNER JOIN
   review ON review.dates = (SELECT review.stuff 
                          FROM review
                          WHERE product.id = review.product_id 
                          ORDER BY review.date ASC
                          LIMIT 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always use `mysql_fetch_array` to grab all of the query info then pass that into a loop to spit out what you need. A similar process can be done with the reviews but if you show the reviews on the same page as the products list, then you can combine both queries using a JOIN query then your only using 1.

[mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

[MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)